# Gitlab CI rule on environment status

Tags: deployment, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

The [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) give some possibilities to run jobs `manual` or `always` (automatically) on a condition.
I want to have a job run `manual` by default, but when there's an [environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment) already running (started by the job), I want the job to run `always`.

The job deploys the project to an [environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment).
So that I don't have all current branches running, I run the job `manual` and create an [environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment).
When there's a new change, I want the relating [environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment) to be updated `always`. The condition is, if there's an [environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment) running.

This is what I have so far:

```yaml
deploy_branch:
  stage: branch
  script:
    - echo "Deploy branch ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
  rules:
    # How can I check for the environment being available?
    - if: …
      when: always
    - when: manual
  environment:
    name: branch/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    url: https://$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG.dev.example.com/
    deployment_tier: development
    on_stop: stop_branch
    auto_stop_in: 2 days

stop_branch:
  stage: branch
  script:
    - echo "Stop branch ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: branch/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    action: stop
```

I think it's not possible at the moment. Is it, or could I achieve this somehow else?

P.S.: Just to be clear, I want to decide on an [environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment) status, not an environment variable status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this with `rules:`. It also wouldn't be particularly helpful even if you could, since `rules:` are evaluated at pipeline creation time, but you would need to know the environment status at the time the job starts, not when the pipeline is created -- that is to say: the environment status can change between pipeline creation time and when the job starts.

What you might do instead is have two jobs: one that runs automatically (on_success) and one that runs manually. The job that runs automatically can check the status of the environment to determine what it should do. If no action is required, it should just exit 0. The manual job will also be available if you want to trigger the deployment manually at any time.

Alternatively, you can use a job to generate a [dynamic child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) to do your deployments. The job can evaluate the status of the environment to determine what the `when:` value should be for the deploy job.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "check/evaluate the status of the environment"? Do you refer to the [GitLab Environments API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#list-environments)?